# Store and recall multiple defined functions from the cloud

Tags: function-construction

I am fairly clear on how to define my own functions in Mathematica.  I have also read the several questions on here about how to create a package so those defined functions can be recalled automatically in each session and have been able to accomplish that automation locally.

I am curious if there is a way to host a package of defined functions in the cloud so that multiple users on different computers can all access the functions.

Would you use a `CloudObject` or a `CloudExpression` or something else or is it even possible?

In an ideal world, we would be able to use something like `AppendTo` so that each user could add new functions that would be available to the other users automatically.

**EDIT**

I first tried doing this with a `CloudExpression` but it didn't work:

```
CreateCloudExpression[doubleInteger[Integer_] := Integer*2;
 squareInteger[Integer_] := Integer*Integer;, testfunctions]
```

> out= CreateCloudExpression[Null, testfunctions]

I was able to successfully upload the package with `CopyFile` and then bring it back in:

```
CopyFile["package.wl", 
 CloudObject[
  "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/ben.kickert/package.wl"]]

Get[CloudObject[
  "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/ben.kickert/package.wl"]]
```

Two questions remain:

1. Is there an easy way to automate that package being brought in from the cloud?  Can I use init.m to bring in a cloud object?
2. Is it possible to append data to a package as a cloud object?  (for instance, will `DumpSave` work on a cloud object?)

Comment: If you have a package file copy that to the cloud with `CopyFile` and the multi-argument form or `CloudObject` to set its permissions. If you want to serialize definitions use `DumpSave`. Now you can dump your definitions to file and copy them to the cloud. After that you can use `CloudImport` to load these definitions. I can expand on this later into a full workflow if that’d be helpful.

Comment: @b3m2a1, I am half way there.  Would love a bit more guidance if you have a chance.